# Angular Js Mutiple Upload Controls with a single upload button

Tags: c#, angularjs, file-upload

I would like to know how can I upload files using multiple upload controls with a single upload button. I have upload control A which uploads images to folder A and upload control B which uploads images to Folder B. When clicks on the upload button $Scope.data lists the 4 files. But these 4 files are selected by two upload controls. How can I know which file is selected by which upload control

Contoller.js

```
$scope.uploadFiles = function () {
    $scope.uploading = true;
    testService.UploadPackageImages($scope)
        // then() called when uploadFiles gets back
        .then(function (data) {
            // promise fulfilled
            $scope.uploading = false;
            if (data === '') {
                alert("Done!!!")
                $scope.formdata = new FormData();
                $scope.data = [];
                $scope.countFiles = '';
                $scope.$apply;
            } else {
                //Server Error
                alert(" What happended up there!!! " + data);
            }
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.uploading = false;
            //Server Error
            alert(" What happended up there!!! " + error);
        }

        );
};
```

Service.js

```
 function uploadPackageImages($scope) {
    debugger;
        var request = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'api/upload/',
            data: $scope.formdata,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            }
        };

        // SEND THE FILES.
        return $http(request)
            .then(
            function (response) {
                if (typeof response.data === 'string') {
                    return response.data;
                } else {
                    return $q.reject(response.data);
                }
            },
            function (response) {
                return $q.reject(response.data);
            }
            );



    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">

                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-12">

                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                                            Browse...<input type="file" multiple my-directory="getFiles(file)" ng-disabled="uploading" />
                                        </span>

                                    </span>
                                    <input type="text" ng-model="countFiles" class="form-control" readonly>
                                </div>
                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default  btn-primary" ng-click="uploadFiles()" value="Upload" ng-disabled="uploading || countFiles===''" />


                                <div ng-repeat="file in data ">
                                    {{file.FileName  + '  ' + file.FileLength + ' bytes'  }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Can you please show your code and what you've tried so far?

Comment: @brijmcq please check the edited question